# How to transpose two-dimension arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, transpose

A table

```
create table matrices(
 matrix text[][] not null);
```

It's value:

```
 insert into Matrices values
    (array[ ['1','2','3'],
            ['4','5','6'] ]),
    (array[ ['a','b','c'],
            ['d','e','f'] ]);
```

How Could I write SQL to transpose each array, so that the result looks like:

```
   matrix
-------------
{{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
{{a,d},{b,e},{c,d}}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: When you are asking for solutions to (my) homework assignments around here, at least invest the effort to replace literals and/or change column and table names.  As is, your postings are rather easy to spot.  —Your Professor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit verbose but here it is

```sql
SELECT array_agg(v ORDER BY j) matrix  FROM (
    SELECT rn, j, array_agg(v ORDER BY i) AS v FROM (
        SELECT rn, i, j, matrix[i][j] AS v FROM (
            SELECT generate_subscripts(matrix, 2) j, q.* FROM (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn,
                       generate_subscripts(matrix, 1) AS i, 
                       matrix                
                  FROM matrices
            ) q
        ) r
    ) s
     GROUP BY rn, j
) t
 GROUP BY rn
 ORDER BY rn;
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a41a1f96cb27c9d81dd96796a21dccff) demo

Or create a function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transpose_2d(anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
SELECT array_agg(v ORDER BY j) matrix  FROM (
    SELECT j, array_agg(v ORDER BY i) AS v FROM (
        SELECT i, j, $1[i][j] AS v FROM (
            SELECT generate_subscripts($1, 2) j, q.* FROM (
                SELECT generate_subscripts($1, 1) AS i, $1
            ) q
        ) r
    ) s
     GROUP BY j
) t
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Usage

```sql
SELECT transpose_2d(matrix) 
  FROM matrices;
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ba75fbceb4d67e45986d3a0962c0a785) demo

---

Output (in both cases):

```
       matrix
---------------------
 {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
 {{a,d},{b,e},{c,f}}
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying this a little:

```
create or replace function array_transpose(arr anyarray)
returns anyarray as
$f$
    select array_agg(
            (select array_agg(arr[i][j] order by i)
                from generate_subscripts(arr, 1) as i)
            order by j
           )
        from generate_subscripts(arr, 2) as j
$f$ 
language sql immutable;
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT (
      ARRAY (
        SELECT matrix[j][s]
        FROM ( SELECT generate_subscripts(matrix, 1) AS j ) foo
      )
    ) 
    FROM ( SELECT generate_subscripts(matrix, 2) AS s ) bar
  ) as matrix
FROM matrices m
```